# How to use a Set in a JPA in clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

How can I get this JPA query working in JPA 2.0?:

```
select r from NLQDatumRegex r where r.tags in :tags
```

(r.tags is a ManyToMany relation. I want to get all entities of type NLQDatumRegex that have tags in the tags list supplied as argument)

If tag is a OneToMany (r.tag) it works, but it won't accept a multiple argument.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to wrap the args in a Collection?

Comment: You mean wrapping r.tags (left part) or :tags (right part)? :tags is a collection indeed passed as an argument. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT r FROM NLQDatumRegex JOIN r.tags t where t in (:tags)`?

Comment: Thanks Dherik. The Eclipse validator returns a warning: "the IN expression does not have a valid left expression"